# Finding the Truth

Tags: ancestry.com, native-american, indiana

I am trying to find information about my maternal great-grandmother.  We were always told that she was a full-blooded Cherokee Indian.  However, in doing a genealogy search, this is the information I found:  She was born on March 29, 1874, in Salamonia, Indiana and her parents were Augustus and Priscilla Burkey Kantner, originally of Pennsylvania, who I don't believe were Native American, but of German heritage.  Her son, my grandfather, looked very much like a Native American as do my uncle and many of my family members. She passed away when I was two years old so I have no memory of her. I do have a photograph of her and my great-grandfather.  Her hair is pulled up and she is dressed in English clothes.

Comment: Do you have specific information that you're looking for, Mary Ellen? As it stands this is a pretty broad question -- if you can narrow it down, you'll get more help (and you can always ask other questions about her later). What is the first thing you want to know? Perhaps: How can I find out if she was Cherokee?

Answer (score 0):

You could try an AncestryDNA test. If you have a parent or grandparent do the test then your maternal great-grandmother's heritage would show more prominently than in your own test.